# How to create Custom UITabBarController in Swift with round button in the center?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm looking to implement a custom `UITabBarController` in **Swift**. I have searched if there is a library or something that can be used to implement exactly same design, but couldn't find any. Most of the answers or libraries are outdated (after some changes that Apple made on *NavigationBar* and *TabBar* on iOS 15), or are not doing the exact same functionality as needed.

So, the TabBar should be with a rounded button in the center, between the button and TabBar should be some transparent space (padding). When that button is tapped it will popup a view.

The design can be seen on the image below.

[image]

Similar logic and UX has Binance app. So, when the button in the center is tapped, it popups a view to navigate to another View Controllers.

[image]

### My Implementation

One of my implementations that worked best is the following one.
I have two classes `CustomTabBarController` and `CustomTabBar`.

**CustomTabBarController**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        setupMiddleButton()
    }

    // TabBarButton – Setup Middle Button
    func setupMiddleButton() {
    
        let middleBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.width / 2)-25, y: -20, width: 50, height: 50))
    
        //STYLE THE BUTTON YOUR OWN WAY
        
        middleBtn.backgroundColor = .blue
        middleBtn.layer.cornerRadius = (middleBtn.layer.frame.width / 2)
    
        //add to the tabbar and add click event
        self.tabBar.addSubview(middleBtn)
        middleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.menuButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

// Menu Button Touch Action
@objc func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedIndex = 2   //to select the middle tab. use "1" if you have only 3 tabs.
    print("MenuButton")
}
}
```

**CustomTabBar**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?
    private func addShape() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        
        //The below 4 lines are for shadow above the bar. you can skip them if you do not want a shadow
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:0)
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 10
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        
        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }
        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.addShape()
    }
    func createPath() -> CGPath {
        let height: CGFloat = 37.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough
        
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: height))
        
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 2), y: 0),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 35, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()
        
        return path.cgPath
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return nil }
        for member in subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
            guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else { continue }
            return result
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

### Results

The results are not quite as expected.
It's not creating a transparency on the curve in center. It's taking background color or sometimes adding just white background. This can be noticed mostly on `TableView` or any other scrolling UI

[image]

As for popup view when Floating Button is pressed I would like to hear any suggestion from you. What would be the best option for that?

Thank you in advance for your contribution.

Comment: There are many, many examples of this that can be found by simple searching. You need to take one that is *"not doing the exact same functionality as needed"* and modify it to fit your needs. If you run into specific problems trying to do that, come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: @DonMag I tried multiple cases and modifying them. Since iOS 15 I cannot add transparency on TabBar below it borders. I implemented this on previous versions, but since September, this is not working anymore. It always adds a white background, no matter how I try to curve the TapBar.

Comment: OK - then you should change your question... you need to say *"Here is the code I'm trying to use to get this tabbar appearance, but I cannot remove the white background."*

Comment: Agree with you, thank you for the suggestion. Will update it in minutes.

Comment: @DonMag please check the update. I'll gladly accept any extra suggestion.

Comment: This is what I get when I run your code as-is (the view background is systemRed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXG8b.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242160/discussion-between-ee-bt-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the visual effect backdrop.

If you're still experiencing the issue, this should fix the problem...

In your `CustomTabBarController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    setupMiddleButton()
    
    // add these two lines
    self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are just missing couple of properties

**1. set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true to each of your vc**

```
class FirVC: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true to each of your vc 
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    }
    
}
```

**2. set BG color of your custom tab bar to clear**

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // set BG color to clear
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        // set BG color to clear
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
```